# apache log configurations not working

Tags: php, apache, redirect, logfile

Hi all apache experts,

i have some trouble edting the apache log file in the remote server, i want to get the count of redirecting in my site with time.

currently the httpd.conf file looks like this

```
LogFormat "%q" count
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/cd?$" dolog
CustomLog "|sudo -u daemon /usr/local/zend/apache2/bin/rotatelogs /var/log/survey/count.log 
3600" impression env=dolog
```

and below is how the log file looks after a redirection, as it takes some of the parameters of the redirecting url(dev.mysite.com/cd?id=121212&track=130&go=http://www.google.com)

```
?id=121212&track=130&go=http://www.google.com
```

my problem is i need to get the time of the this redirection therefore i have done a modification to the httpd.conf file as follows, to get the time in the log file

```
LogFormat "%q %t" count
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/cd?$" dolog
CustomLog "|sudo -u daemon /usr/local/zend/apache2/bin/rotatelogs /var/log/survey/count.log 
3600" impression env=dolog
```

but it hasnt made any difference... therefore please can anyone help on this to get the "time" written on the log file...

Answer (score 0):

You defined a LogFormat named "count", but you're using a LogFormat named "impression" in your CustomLog directive.  These strings have to match, or changes are obviously not going to show up.